# Python type hint multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

How can I provide accurate type hints for a Python object that inherits from two specific classes?

```py
class BaseClass1:
    pass


class BaseClass2:
    pass


class MyClass1(BaseClass1, BaseClass2):
    pass


class MyClass2(BaseClass1, BaseClass2):
    pass


def foo(ins: WhatTypingHere?): 
    pass


i1 = MyClass1()

i2 = MyClass2()

foo(i1)
foo(i2)
```

I tried this, but I don't know how correct it is

```py
T = type[BaseClass1] & type[BaseClass2]
T = TypeVar("I18nField", bound= BaseClass1 | BaseClass2)
```

Comment: Intersection typing is not yet implemented per [PEP-483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks) and [PEP-544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#provide-a-special-intersection-type-construct).